# Conditional Field drupal 8 for a content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am looking to hide/show some fields depending upon user selection on another field. So a user can select among four wheeler/two wheeler. If user selects four wheeler from a dropdown he is shown different set of fields and for two wheeler different set of fields . As there are many common fields I am looking to use same content type for both content type

What I have tried so far is

1. Theme_name_form_alter hook in theme_name.theme file
2. As well as hook_form_FORM_ID_alter

None seems to be working for me

Answer (score 1):

while [Conditional Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) still is in development on Drupal 8 So
[Field Formatter Condition Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fico) could be a good choice.

> Simple conditions and actions
>
> Hide source field when target field is empty. Hide source field when
>   target field is not empty. Hide source field when the current user has
>   specific roles. Hide source field on specific pages. Hide source field
>   when target field contains a specific string. Hide source field when
>   target field doesn't contain a specific string. Hide link field if
>   title is empty. Hide date field if smaller/greater then today/custom
>   date. Hide if content from author Hide if checkbox is checked (in
>   current dev version)

Answer (score 0):

Module conditional fields is still dev for Drupal 8 but should work:

https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Answer (score -1):

And in case "Conditional fields" is not working for you maybe "Paragraphs" can jump in as replacement. It's stable at least.

https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs

Not exactly what you were asking for, but can do the job.